# Workflow Manager consumes 100% CPU Usage

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager, service

Our SharePoint server and Workflow Manager is installed only in a Single Server Farm. As of now we have 6 site collections and we used workflow 2013 to all of our list and document libraries.And for the past months we noticed that Workflow Service Back end ,Service Bus and Front End service causing to spike the CPU usage to 100% consistently.

Due to issues reported by our end users that our sites takes really slow and we decided to stop the workflow manager backend.

What we did today is installed CU3 update for Workflow Manager but still it consumes CPU usage and we running out of solution.

Is there anything that we need to check why is this happening when thew workflow is enabled? We need some of your recommendation and suggestions.

Thanks!